# Regular expression for presuffix and suffix with characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to prepare the regular expression for below mentioned formats to accept. I tried some options which did not work and getting the error like "pattern syntax exception: error parsing regexp: invalid nested repetition operator: ?+

```
abc 12345678 - should be true
abc12345678abc - should be true
#12345678 - should be true
12345678# - should be true
12345678 - should be false
```

I have tried below

```
^([a-zA-Z]) ?+([0-9]{8}) ?+([a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z]) ?+([0-9]{8})|([0-9]{8}) ?+([a-zA-Z])|(# ?+)([0-9]{8})( ?#+)|(# ?+)([0-9]{8})|([0-9]{8})( ?#+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?+` from your regex is an optional but posessive quantifier which javascript doesn't support (at least in this syntax) demo here: https://regex101.com/r/aLOqhS/1 (see error on right hand side)

Solution would be to use quantifiers and methods supported by JS, one such attempt:

`(?<=^[a-zA-Z#\s]+)\d+|\d+(?=[a-zA-Z#\s]+$)`

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/9moHi8/1